# How to get previous data when I click add row dynamically in angular 6?

Tags: typescript, angular6

```js
  addFieldValue() {
       this.newarray= this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
       console.log(this.newarray);
        this.newAttribute = {};
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <td>
              <input [(ngModel)]="field.SourceIP" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{field.SourceIP}}" />
          </td>
          <button mat-button  (click)="addFieldValue()">Add More Rule
        <i class="material-icons custom">add</i>
</button>
```

```js
 addFieldValue() {
       this.newarray= this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
       console.log(this.newarray);
        this.newAttribute = {};
    }

    deleteFieldValue(index: number) {
        this.fieldArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

When I am adding dynamic row in my table I can't able to see previous data of row.I  am using Angular 6?

Here I am entering data after the click of add I am losing my previous data after adding a row

[image]

Comment: You have to store existing binded data into one local variable and then add a new record in that variable

Comment: But I can able to display one column data I haven't used any local storage over there??

Comment: Can you show the tried code?

Comment: I have added my ts file functionality

Comment: I`m not sure whats the problem.
From what I see you have fieldArray which spouse to have your
data you are looking for.
We gonna need more then those 2 rows.
Basically you so many ways to do what you want to do, 
just need to see your code to know whats fit to you.

Comment: @AkhilRaghav Explanation required about current and expected outpue or it would be better to provide stackblitz

Comment: Sir,I have added piece of my functionality here If I am adding one more input form my previous form value is not showing in form box

Comment: Good it would be better if you provide all related code for ex: Table HTML and TS file

Comment: Post the related HTML and TS file!

Comment: yes it is Ts file

Comment: When you add a new item to the model that you have used to generate the table (i think you use ngFor to generate table) is changed. And since the model is changed the table is regenerate again. You can try by store the model in a variable and use that variable to generate the table.